# ClientSecret definition not found in FacebookClient (DotNetOpenAuth)

Tags: facebook, dotnetopenauth

I am trying to using FacebookClient (DotNetOpenAuth.ApplicationBlock). Everywhere on the Internet I have seen the below code:

```
   FacebookClient fbClient = new FacebookClient
                {
                    ClientIdentifier = "appId",
                    ClientSecret = "appSecret"
                };
```

But when compiling it gives error: **'DotNetOpenAuth.ApplicationBlock.FacebookClient' does not contain a definition for 'ClientSecret'**

What could be the reason? Why it is able to locate ClientIdentifier and not ClientSecret.

I have downloaded DotNetOpenAuth.ApplicationBlock from [DotNetOpenAuth's GitHub](https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth) repository.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found from the source code and samples that in new version of DotNetOpenAuth.ApplicationBlock, ClientSecret has been removed. Instead, now it should be:

```
FacebookClient fbClient = new FacebookClient
{
                ClientIdentifier = "appId",
                ClientCredentialApplicator = ClientCredentialApplicator.PostParameter("appSecret")
};
```